# How do you get data out of brackets and curly braces in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to pull info out of google searches using the py-web-search module. The result of pulling a search is this(as stated in the [Github](https://github.com/rohithpr/py-web-search#usage)):

```
{
    'url': '...',
    'expected_num': 5,
    'received_num' : 5, # There will be a difference in case of insufficient results
    'start': 2,
    'search_engine': 'google',
    'total_results': ...,
    'results':
    [
        {
            'link': '...',
            'link_text': '...',
            'link_info': '...',
            'related_queries': [...],
            'additional_links':
            {
                linktext: link,
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

and I can't seem to figure out how to print the 'link' data out.

```
result=Google.search(query='hello world', num=5, start=0, country_code="es")
data=result['results']
print(data)
```

This is my test code, which only prints `[]`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Lists (square brackets) are indexed by a number only, starting at 0. Dictionaries (curly braces), are typically indexed by dot-notation or also by square brackets, but with a string. Does that help?

Comment: Looks like what your trying is ok, but I would suggest trying to print result variable to see if the results entry in the dictionary actually has any result in it.

Comment: the data is in json format. Use a json module in python to extract the data or dump the data to a dictionary.

Comment: That's not JSON, people. It's a python dictionary

Comment: It's clearly not JSON, because it has single quotes; JSON is very strict about such things, only double quotes are valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, but that library is out-of-date and does not return any results for Google searches. See [this issue](https://github.com/rohithpr/py-web-search/issues/20) for details:

> Also, Google has changed the HTML structure. So the scraper has to be updated. Thanks for the bug report!

As a temporary workaround, you can consider using Bing as your search engine as it still works:

```
from pws import Bing
result = Bing.search('hello world', 5, 2)
print(result["results"])
```

Comment: Just tested it and that's exactly what I'm seeing. `{'search_engine': 'google', 'received_num': 0, 'expected_num': 10, 'country_code': None, 'start': 0, 'url': 'https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world&num=10&start=0', 'related_queries': ['hello world lyrics', 'hello world html', 'hello world song', 'hello world python', 'hello world java', 'hello world book', 'hello world c++', 'hello world tutorial'], 'total_results': 35100000, 'results': []}`

Comment: @J.B Exactly, the `results` list is empty.

Comment: Thanks guys. Thought I was doing something wrong there. Do you know of any libraries that work for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, try to look at [this source file](https://github.com/rohithpr/py-web-search/blob/master/pws/google.py) (line 119), where result is parsed: `raw_results = soup.find_all('li', attrs = {'class' : 'g'})`. In other words it based on 'li' tags, but if you look at HTML code of google result there are no li tags there.